# FreeBSD: Samba performance over GBit-Ethernet

Tags: performance, samba, freebsd

I'm using a FreeBSD NAS with RAID-Z.

I can read ~300MB/s from the ZFS disks to /dev/null on the box, but only get about 50MB/s over GBit-Ethernet with SMB to Windows 7 (Samba 3.5.6). Both systems have Intel-PCIe-NICs and are connected directly.

Samba is configured to use AIO and I already tried to tune TCP/IP:

```
kern.ipc.maxsockbuf=16777216
net.inet.tcp.sendspace=1048576
net.inet.tcp.recvspace=1048576
net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_max=8388608
net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_max=8388608
net.inet.tcp.delayed_ack=0
```

Any ideas what's causing the bottleneck? I think the link should handle 100 MB/s easily.

Comment: How old are the systems? I was just working with someone yesterday with the exact same issue and they were using an 8 year old server that simply couldn't push more than ~48MB/s over a NIC. Try using `netperf` (in the ports tree)?

Comment: @Chris S: PCIe slots aren't so old

Comment: Are you using jumbo frames?

Comment: The system is new (Athlon II X2 2,8Ghz). No I'm not using jumbo frames. But I don't think they would improve the throughput that much?

Comment: FreeNAS allows exporting the same files through different means.  Try transferring the same files using a different protocol.  If the speed changes, it's the protocol, if the speed doesn't change, then it's hardware or configuration.

Comment: @Javier, what does PCIe have to do with anything? @bot403, jumbo frames increase efficiency, but at most 10%. @Marcin, the ram drive test is a good idea. @Axel, definitely need to benchmark trying different combinations, it should be faster than that.

Comment: @Chris S: not much, just that in the original question it was the only detail that gave a hint about system age.  I don't think you can get a Pentium machine with a PCIe card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there actually were two problems:

1. Jumbo frames weren't so irrelevant after all. That gave me a huge performance boost.
2. My SSD disk can easily write 100 MB/s, but I recently turned on NTFS compression which created problems (second long stalls while writing). A TRIM optimization resolved that.

Answer (score 0):

To test the cable and bandwidth of your drivers, you should take out hard disk (and anti-virus for the windows box) write limits.

So you can either:

- create a RAM disk on the windows box, download/push files onto it
- create and redirect a samba share to /dev/null and push files into it from the windows box
- run a cross-platform bandwidth utility (probably part of the Intel NIC utilities on the windows platform).

If anyone knows of a cross-platform windows-unix benchmark tool, please let me/us know :-)

And yes, you will need to make sure you have matching jumbo frames (2048 Bytes seems to be the 'norm') on your nics and switch. The standard TCP/IP packet size is a bit small for Gigabit streams.

Comment: netperf works on Windows and Unix